# Is there any analog of ASP.NET master page in pure JSP?

Tags: asp.net, jsp

Pls give a link with sample if possible

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't read your question properly.

The answer would be: no.

But, if you can use JSF, [Facelets templates](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/) are pretty similar to ASP.NET master pages.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/jsf-asp/), JSP does not have an equivalent technology:

> Although various JSF IDEs offer page
>   templating to a certain extent such as
>   IBM page templating, there is not yet
>   a uniform easy way to build page
>   templates such as how you use
>   Microsoft "Master Page" templating
>   technology.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.  [Here](http://p2p.wrox.com/jsp-basics/68395-master-page-jsp.html) is an idea of how you might put one together that sort of works like ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET master page is a templating technology. JSP itself is already *less or more* a templating technology. There's under each the `<jsp:include>` tag to include templates. You can use it dynamically with EL, but it is however not very advanced/enhanced. [Facelets](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) has brought changes in it.

> JavaServer Pages<sup>TM</sup> (JSP<sup>TM</sup>) technology, previously used as the presentation technology for JavaServer Faces, does not support all of the new features available in JavaServer Faces 2.0. JSP is considered as a **deprecated** presentation technology for JavaServer Faces 2.0.

On Facelets you can use [JSF](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html), which is a component based MVC framework like ASP.NET MVC.

Alternatives outside the Java EE API are [Apache Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/) and [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/).